# How to get accumulative maximum indices with numpy in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, max, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to get `x` and `y` coordinates of all cumulative maximums in a vector.  I wrote a naive `for-loop` but I have a feeling there is some way to do it with `numpy` that's more elegant.

Does anyone know of any functions, masking-technique, or one-liners in `numpy` that can do this?

The details should be described by the plot below:

```
# Generate data
x = np.abs(np.random.RandomState(0).normal(size=(100)))
y = np.linspace(0,1,x.size)
z = x*y

# Get maximiums
idx_max = list()
val_max = list()

current = 0
for i,v in enumerate(z):
    if v > current:
        idx_max.append(i)
        val_max.append(v)
        current = v

# Plot them
with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3), ncols=2)
    ax[0].plot(z)
    ax[1].plot(z, alpha=0.618)
    ax[1].scatter(idx_max, val_max, color="black", edgecolor="maroon", linewidth=1.618)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could make use of [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) -

```
idx_max = np.flatnonzero(np.isclose(np.maximum.accumulate(z),z))[1:]
val_max = z[idx_max]
```

The basic idea being that this `accumulative max` value when compared with the current element indicates which are the element positions responsible for "uplifting" the running max value. The responsible ones are the indices that we need as `idx_max`. Since, we are working with floating-pt numbers, we need to incorporate some tolerance with that `np.isclose`.

That `[1:]` part is because the starting current value was `0` and so was `z[0]`. So, that `v > current` part won't append that starting index into output. To be precisely correct about it, it should had been -

```
current = 0
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.isclose(np.maximum.accumulate(z),z))
idx = idx[z[idx] > current]
```

But, given the starting values, the assumption made earlier keeps our code easier/compact/short.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this same question for some time and the answer was still not satisfactory for the problem I needed to solve, because I needed the respective indices of the maximum values accumulated in an array with the same shape. That is, if a certain maximum value were to repeat `n` times, it would need `n` positions with that index value. My alternative answer follows:

```
# create sample array
a = np.array([5,4,8,1,4,9,5,3])

# generate index for the array
idx = np.indices(a.shape)

# calculate accumulate maximum values and
# the number of repetitions of that
acc = np.maximum.accumulate(a)
_, repeats = np.unique(acc, return_counts=True)

# relating the closest value to the indx with boolean values
close  = np.isclose(a, acc)

# this generate an array with 3 elements,
idx[0, close]

# but the original has 8
# so, we are able to repeat the max indices as simpla as this
np.repeat(idx[0, close], repeats)

# array([0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5])
```